# Proving throught induction

Tags: induction

How do I prove the following inquation using induction?

$2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$ ,
$n\geq 2$

I did the base case, but I'm stuck at the induction process.

The induction: $2^{k+1}>1+(k+1)\sqrt{2^{k}}$

Now I used the hipothesis to prove the induction:

$2*2^{k}>2*(1+k\sqrt{2^{k-1}})$

$2^{k+1}>2+2k\sqrt{2^{k-1}})$

I can´t do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hip: $2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$.

Then,

$2 \cdot 2^n>2(1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}})$

$2^{n+1}>2+2n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}=2+n\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2^{n}}>1+(n+1)\sqrt{2^{n}}$

since $n\sqrt{2}>n+1$, if $n>2$.

Comment: thank you I got it

Comment: I believe your answer doesn't prove the inequation it should be: $1+(n+1)\sqrt{2^{n}}$

Comment: you're right, i've already corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your induction hypothesis be $2^k > 1 + k\sqrt{2^{k-1}}$ for some integer $k \geq 2$? It looks like you assumed $2^k > 1 + k\sqrt{2^{k}}$ instead.

Comment: I typed it wrong, but I assumed it right, sorry. I already edited.